# Serverless framework and workaround for conditional value

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

After reading Serverless documentation and a few posts in their forum, I noticed there is no way to implement a clear conditional attribution.

I want to set one or other values based on the stage.

```
provider:
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'production'}

custom:
  domain: here's where the conditional should set one or the other value
```

So, if the stage is production custom.domain should hold the value: [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), but if it's development, it should hold www-dev.mydomain.com

I found some libraries/plugins like https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse but most of them are outdated.

Do you know a workaround to achieve this without installing plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commonly used workaround is to define per-stage values and use variable resolution to route to the specific one.

```
custom:
  stageTargets:
    dev:
      domain: dev.foobar.com
    prod:
      domain: foobar.com
  target: ${self:custom.stageTargets.${self:custom.stage}}
  domain: ${self:custom.target.domain}
```